# Django: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user', although it is defined

Tags: python, django, request, nonetype

I'm new to django, and trying to use this code to get an image url and save it to the database:

```
@login_required
def image_create(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    #form is sent
    form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        #form data is valid
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        new_item = form.save(commit=False)

        #assign current user to the item:
        new_item.user = request.user
        new_item.save()
        messages.success(request, 'image added successfully')

        #redirect to the new created item detail view:
        return redirect(new_item.get_absolute_url())
else:
    #build the form with the data provided by bookmarklet via GET:
    form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.GET)

return render(request, 'images/image/create.html', {'section': 'images', 'form': form})
```

but when I try to add an image using this url:

> localhost/images/create/?title=IMAGE_NAME&url=SOME_URL

i get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /images/create/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'
```

and it points to line  17 of the view, which is:

```
new_item.user = request.user
```

I'd be grateful of your help!

Comment: post the model and the form

Comment: Perhaps you have overriden the form's `save()` method, and are returning `None` by mistake.